# How to make the setTimeout sequential for multiple database updates?

Tags: node.js, express, settimeout

I am updating database fields by using setTimeout(). So when the updates are multiple what happens is the the last primary key is used for all the updates. How do I run the setTimeout() function sequentially. Below is the portion of code which does that.

```
for( var i = 0; i < req.body.devicelist.length; i++) {     //running for loop for multiple elements 
   var data = JSONPARSE.toObject(req.body);
   mac_id = req.body.devicelist[i];
   data.mac_id = mac_id;
   var gateway_config;

   for (let j = 0; j < gateways_config.length; j++) {                 //code for fetching specific element. IGNORE
      if(gateways_config[j].latest_config.mac_id == mac_id){
         gateway_config = gateways_config[j]
         break;
      }
         gateway_config = undefined
   }
   
   await syncConfig(req.body,gateway_config, req.decoded.id);  
   ..........
   ..........
}


syncConfig(body,gateway,user_id){
   var jsonObj = body;
   ...
   ...
   ...
   config_timeout_array[jsonObj.mac_id] = setTimeout(() => {       //Causing problem
      commandTimeout(jsonObj.org_id,jsonObj.mac_id)
   }, 10000);
   ...
   ...
}

commandTimeout:(org_id, mac_id) =>{
   
   console.log(mac_id);  //prints same mac_id (the last in the array)

   return gateway_model.findOneAndUpdate({ org_id: org_id, mac_id: mac_id }, { 'sync_sent': false }, {"new": true})
      .then((updated_gateway) => {
         ...
         ...
         ...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config_timeout_array[jsonObj.mac_id] = setTimeout(() => {       //Causing problem
      commandTimeout(jsonObj.org_id,jsonObj.mac_id)
   }, 10000);
```

Instead of doing the above logic directly, call a function and do it there. I don't know why but it worked!

```
seqTimeout(jsonObj.org_id,jsonObj.mac_id);       //function call


seqTimeout(org_id,mac_id){
    config_timeout_array[mac_id] = setTimeout(() => {
        GatewayController.commandTimeout(org_id, mac_id);
    }, COMMAND_TIMEOUT);
}
```